# Difference between using : in assignment and in for-loop

Tags: matlab

I wrote a simple for loop:

```
>> for m=1:3
p=m;
end
>> whos
  Name       Size                   Bytes  Class

  m          1x1                        8  double array
  p          1x1                        8  double array
```

But when I try to create a data type of same class for a range and check what variables you now have stored its not of 1x1 size:

```
>> k=1:256;

>> whos
  Name       Size                   Bytes  Class

  k          1x256                   2048  double array
  m          1x1                        8  double array
  p          1x1                        8  double array
```

Why there is a difference in-between the variables sizes of m and k? If I understand correctly 1x1 size(variable 'm') means that it is a matrix of 1x1 order. So why k becomes 1x256 order?

Comment: Type `k` at the command prompt and see what the response is.

Comment: `m` is a single value, so it has a size of a single `double`. When you create `k` you're creating an array of `256 doubles` - and since each `double` is `8 bytes` you end up with `2048 bytes` - this should be what you expect.

Comment: The semantics of the [`colon` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) in a `for` statement are very different from its use in a bare assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is because you are declaring `k` as a 256 element vector. The `:` operator creates a vector for example like

```
a = 1:5

    a == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

where as with `m` you are creating it in a for loop which works differently. The values of `m` loop from 1 to 3 (i.e. they iterate over the vector `[1,2,3]`) but at any one point `m` is just a scalar (at the end of the loop it has a value of 3) hence as you have it `m` is a 1x1.

So if you do it the other way around then you'll get:

`for k = 1:256` gives you a 1x1 `k`

but

`m = 1:3` will give you a 1x3 vector for `m` (`m == [1,2,3]`)

Comment: `m` will be a single value (`1x1`) actually at the end since it takes the values of the vector `1:3` as it iterates.

Comment: I see the edits are closing in on it. There's still some confusion about `k` as asked in the question though (which is different than in the answer at this point). If `k=1:256` (as in the question) it will be `1x256`, not `1x1`

Comment: @tmpearce the first sentence of the answer states that `k` is 1x256 and then explains why. The 1x1 is just an example to illustrate the difference between the two methods in the OP.